# ng-class expression not change dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

complete code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/yougen/duUsr/

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="app">
    <div class="deal" deal-over>
        <div class="deal-img">
            <a href="/somewhere">
                   <img src="path/to/img" alt="should add a img">
            </a>
            <div class="state-box" ng-class="{dealOver:dealOver,dealOut:dealOut}">
                <a href="/target-deal">Here show tips when hover</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

directive:

```
app.directive('dealOver', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('mouseenter', function () {
                scope.dealOver = true;
                scope.dealOut = false;
                //how to find div.state-box element from elem? elem.find('.state-box') not work
                //elem.css({"opacity":0.9,"display":"block"});
            });

            elem.bind("mouseleave", function () {
                scope.dealOver = false;
                scope.dealOut = true;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Goal:**: div.state-box show when mouseenter, hide when mouseleave

**Problem**: it seems like ng-class style never change.

**Addition**: in the beginning, I want to change the style of the div.state-box in the directive, but I don't know how to get the div.state-box element in the directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to let Angular know that you've updated the scope.

Do so by passing a function to `scope.$apply`:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.bind('mouseenter', function () {
        scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.dealOver = true;
            scope.dealOut = false;
        });
    });

    elem.bind("mouseleave", function () {
        scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.dealOver = false;
            scope.dealOut = true;
        });
    });
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/duUsr/7/

Comment: thanks, it works. Another question is in the addition part, how could get a child element by class in the directive? For my example, I want to get the div.state-box element in the directive, so I can change it by element.css('...').